# Reading a program's own memory as data

Tags: c, ram, buffer-overflow

I'm watching [Mario glitch](https://youtu.be/E5y2SpFWfUo?t=4m37s)

Where the Mario gameboy cartridge reads its own memory as level data.

How can I get access to the current memory of a program I'm running? (Any language though I'm thinking C or Assembly is the place to start)

Comment: Just a couple of thoughts... 
You can try stack smashing. Or you can attach a 1 byte shared memory segment to your process image and attempt to read beyond its size.

Comment: Reading levels from program's memory and reading random positions in your program's memory is not the same thing. The first one is perfectly legal, while the second one is undefined behavior.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, in assembly it is actually all the same thing just what register sets you are working with. You certainly have to read and interact with the stack pointer a lot to do anything interesting in assembly. And the assembly is the instruction memory. Of course, reading another processes memory is always bad and doing something crazy like writing to stack or instruction memory will almost always crash something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In assembly you can read the [ESP (stack pointer) and EIP (instruction pointer)](http://www.eecg.toronto.edu/~amza/www.mindsec.com/files/x86regs.html) registers directly. They will have the address to the top of the stack and the current instruction respectively. From there you can read the memory that is the stack and instructions directly.

In that video they overrun the level data and the game started interpreting the stack data as level data. He then writes to an offset in the stack by breaking bricks that contain the memory for the next level to enter.

Since it is always the same bricks with that same data that means the memory layout is very deterministic which is no surprise for an old cartridge system where nothing else is running on the processor. You could straight up write the data if you had console access and knew the offset.